# Conflict SDMMC + freertos cubie

Tags: stm32, freertos, multitasking, mcu, sdmmc

I am using CUBIDE for programming stm32l452. When I enable SDMMC without rtos then I can communicate with SD card from main function (outside of while loop). When I enable freertos without any changes in programm SDmmc stops communication, but mounting is successful. Who can help me to solve this problem I need to write SD from one task and parallely get data from another task via spi. Thanks.

```
`void main
    {
        f_mount(); // 
        f_open();
        f_write();
        f_close();

        while(1)
            {
               HAL_Delay(1000);
            }
    }`
```

Comment: To use FATFS when using FreeRTOS, you must enable the FS_REENTRANT and SyncObject  option in the settings of fatfs.  This can be done in the CubeIDE FATFS entry or in ffconf.h. See https://github.com/Bsm-B/Stm32-FatFs-FreeRTOS

Comment: Both are enabled, are there other suggestions?

Comment: Solved !   REENTRANT in RTOS must be enabled and FS_REENTRANT in Fatfs must be deceabled.